# extract multiple items on single line using grep/sed/perl

Tags: linux, bash, perl, sed, tr

I have a massive text file a bit like this:

```
=?accession=P12345;=?position=999;
=?accession=Q19283;=?position=777;
=?accession=A918282;=?position=888;
```

and I would like to extract terms between `accession=` and `;`, and then also between `position=` and `;`

so that I get:

```
P12345 999
Q19283 777
A918282 888
```

The strings I need to grep between do get more complicated, so I imagine a hardcoded solution.

I know I can take the "grep between two strings" approach:

```
grep -Po 'accession= \K.*(?= ;)'
```

but I don't know how to get subsequent extractions from the same line of the input to also appear on the same line as the output.

I really don't mind how this is done as long as I can call it from a linux command line.

Thanks.

Comment: How can we help you come up with a script to parse your data if the sample you show us is only `a bit like` your real data? This feels like we'll be peeling the onion for a while before getting to your real requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can update your **grep** expression like this.

   ```
   grep -oP "(accession=\K\w+)|(position=\K\d+)" file
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   P12345
   999
   Q19283
   777
   A918282
   888
   ```

   To format it the way you want, use `paste` :

   ```
   grep -oP "(accession=\K\w+)|(position=\K\d+)" file | paste -d ' ' - -
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   P12345 999
   Q19283 777
   A918282 888
   ```
2. Another simple **awk** solution :

   ```
   awk -F"=|;" '{print $3, $6}' file
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   P12345 999
   Q19283 777
   A918282 888
   ```

Comment: @brucezepplin: You can slightly modify your grep as mentioned here . Cheers !

Comment: thanks very much - that paste command was the key, and the `\K\w+` is neat. thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)  Welcome ^_^

Comment: Fantastic!  To make this an even stronger answer might consider adding a little explanation around that paste command (yes, people can rtfm to understand why two hyphens but that info could be included here to save them an extra google search :) )

Answer (score 2):

This perl one-liner

```
perl -wnE'say join " ", /(?:accession|position)=([^;]+)/g' input.txt
```

prints the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should work:

```
awk -F ';' '{gsub(/=[^=]*=/, ""); $1=$1} 1' file

P12345 999
Q19283 777
A918282 888
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/.*accession=([^;]*);.*position=([^;]*).*/\1 \2/' textfile
```